# zend validate multi select box

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

i am using zend validations in my form and i could not validate a multi select box in my form.

**This is my multi select element in the form:**

```
$days = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('day');
$days->setLabel('Days')
->addMultiOptions($total_days)
->setRequired(true)
->addValidator('NotEmpty')
->setAttrib('multiple', 'multiple');
```

**I get the following error during form submission, even when i select some option in the multiselect box:**

> *Array was not found in the haystack*

And i see the following code in Zend/Validate/InArray.php, that can validate only single form elements, but not arrays:

```
public function isValid($value)
{
$this->_setValue($value);
if (in_array($value, $this->_haystack, $this->_strict)) 
{
return true;
}
}
```

But how can i resolve the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To have multi select elements in your form, you should be using [Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect), not Zend_Form_Element_Select, eg:

```
$days = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('day');
$days->setLabel('Days')
->addMultiOptions($total_days)
->setRequired(true)
->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```